# why we need to casting views in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm just was wondering why we are actually casting views when we initialize it by using findViewById() method, I mean what does findViewById() method return back, and why we need to cast the result.

```
TextView txtview;

txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: You are not initializing, you are assigning there from a already created view object with childs

In the past the signature of the method was

```
public View findViewById(@ResId int id)
```

The downcast from View to any subtype (TextView, EditText, ImageView, etc) was necessary and old articles still uses this method.

Now days the signature is generic as:

```
public <T extends View> T findViewById(@ResId int id)
```

Meaning it returns it value cast to T, T is resolved with the left side of the assignment declaration (before the equals) so we can simply do:

```
TextView t = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_x);
```

The value of T is TextView from the left side of the assignment.

Also consider the following method signature:

```
void x(TextView t, ImageView i)
```

You can infer T while calling this resulting the method being called with a Textview and a ImageView instead of the super class View:

```
x(view.findViewById(R.id.tv_x), view.findViewById(R.id.iv_x))
```

While this assignment would need downcasting:

```
View v = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_x);
//v.text = "x" HERE we don't know the type was not infered to TextView
((TextView) v).text = "x"; //unsafe downcasting necessary
```

Ps: the inferred type of T is unsafe below View

Answer (score 0):

This casting is actually optional. Please check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)) that this call returns the view or null otherwise

Alternatively if you use view binding you don't even need to use `findViewById`